# Serial voting reversal does not reverse the votes, just the reputation. Why not?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

This one has been nagging me for a while (i.e. some years) and finally I've decided to ask about it.

I have noticed that when serial voting is reversed, it is the reputation change that is reversed. However, the votes that were cast are not reversed and so the score of the post remains influenced by the serial voting.

I know that individuals can get worked up by the reputation loss caused by serial downvoting, and I quite understand that. However, thinking more widely about the site, isn't the score of a post more important?

To give an example, I have to reach for one of my own posts, because of course I don't have any other way to find posts that have been subject to serial voting. So, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355865/) currently has a score of -5 (1 upvote, 6 downvotes). The majority of these downvotes were part of serial voting episodes. I guess that serial voters might look for the post with the lowest score, and start there, which I suspect is why it has such a low score. Note that I'm not trying to claim that this question is the greatest question in the history of SO, but I equally don't think it's really a -5 kind of a question.

Anyway, examples aside, my question is why serial voting reversal does not also remove the vote? It seems to me that the score of a post is more important than the reputation changes associated with the voting, and that the current system is more focused on the feelings of the posters rather than the information being provided to future readers of the posts.

Comment: The votes do get invalidated, but the scores simply don't update until the next round of cache invalidation (which I was told is once a day, can't find the thread anymore). Very annoying and I completely agree with the sentiment here. Everyone on meta acts like the only thing we care about when serially downvoted is our reputation - even when reputation was never part of the conversation. While it's true that many users don't look past their reputation, not everyone is like that.

Comment: @BoltClock Looking at my rep audit for that post I can see that you are right. I think that the bulk of the DVs on that post are part of serial voting episodes that weren't reverted, because the serial voter only cast a handful of votes and avoided the scripts. So I guess I should remove this post because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Well, it is true that post scores don't update in the same instant the rep changes are reversed, which can mean the difference between ranking a 0 post equally and ranking a -1 post lower, giving the impression that the votes themselves haven't been reversed.

Comment: Post scores do get corrected if the script detects fraud.  Beware that most of those posts were downvoted before so it is not so easy to see that the score got restored.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804876/do-i-need-to-add-synchronization-to-this-code) wasn't, it shows the correct score.  The timeline on the [quoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32355865/timeline) looks good too, 6 downvotes total and the last one was 17/7/17.  It all seems to check out fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I, for one, would love to have a good post like this one to point duplicates to..

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. As I commented above I can now see that my question was based on a false premise. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the timeline feature, that's a new one for me.

Comment: I thought that the question was about "downvoters shouldn't regain their reps after serial downvoting"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The votes **are** reversed, just not the cached *score* of a post, not immediately. The scores of posts affected are re-cached at a later point, by a batch process that runs at midnight UTC every day.

Until the batch process runs, you can force a recalculation of a post score by clicking on the score (as long as you have 1000 reputation for [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)); this fetches the up- and down-vote counts, and gives you an accurate score calculated from these. At the same time the cached score is updated.

The process has already run for the posts you were serially voted on yesterday, *or* someone already triggered a re-caching for all those posts manually.

Comment: Finally, David can sleep at night!!

Comment: @corsiKa If only!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is the score per tag in the profile page also recalculated after the reversal?

Comment: @adiga: yes, tag scores are also recalculated, once every 24h.

Comment: I can confirm that the score is wrong even after 24h. I asked a similar question that I deleted (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398013/votes-arent-updated-when-voting-is-corrected) and I followed the score of that user and still no update of many of them.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I see no wrong scores on that user account.

Comment: when I posted the comment yesterday there is still some wrong scores, maybe no more today but It was after more than 24h from the "User was removed" and I noticed this many time. It get more than 24 to update. Will try to bring another example next time (in time )

Comment: @TemaniAfif so? The batch process gets to it eventually.